# Where's the "Allow this precompiled site to be updatable" check in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, msdeploy

I need to do [this](http://www.nathanblevins.com/2008/06/compile-a-web-user-control-into-a-dll-net-c/) but one step leads me to uncheck the "Allow this precompiled site to be updatable" option, but I don't see that in the publish website dialog on Visual Studio 2010.

Does anyone know how can I do that on Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This option is available for **ASP.Net Web Site** projects not **ASP.Net Web Applications**. Right click on the solution explorer and select Add New Web Site...against that you will get that checkbox

Check out this [Web Application Projects versus Web Site Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx), Under Summary of Differences, you will see:

**Compilation:**

*Web application projects*

1. You explicitly compile the source code on the computer that is used for development or source control.
2. By default, compilation of code files (excluding .aspx and .ascx files) produces a single assembly.

*Web site projects*

3. The source code is typically compiled dynamically (automatically) by ASP.NET on the server the first time a request is received after the site has been installed or updated.
4. **You can precompile the site (compile in advance on a development computer or on the server).**
5. By default, compilation produces multiple assemblies.

Comment: Answer is still proving useful :D

Answer (score 3):

For **ASP.Net Web Applications**

1. Web application Properties
2. Package/Publish Web
3. Tick precompile this application before publishing
4. Go to Advanced option
5. Select Do not merge. Create a separate assembly for each page and control