# How to decompile *.compiled file in C#?

Tags: asp.net, c#-2.0

I have a website and i can open it with the VS 2005, but it has been compiled.When it has been compiled,I did not check "Allow this precompile site to be updatable" . Now i wanna see them and make some changes. I don't know how.

Comment: You don't have the original source?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this

1. In Visual Studio, open a web application project.
2. Right click the project name in Solution Explorer, and then choose Publish.
3. Select the Settings tab.
4. Expand File Publish Options, and then select Precompile during publishing.
5. Click Configure.

reference: [Advanced Precompile Settings Dialog Box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh475319.aspx)

you may also check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11151567/wheres-the-allow-this-precompiled-site-to-be-updatable-check-in-visual-studio). This could be a possible duplicate.